# anything like a java object in abap programming?

Tags: abap

is there any type of `Object` in abap, so that I can save any kind of data in it?

the reason is the following:
I'm writing some code and I dont know what kind of data I will get back. If I would work with java I would save it in a `Object`.

Is there something equal in ABAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for data types, there is a [generic type](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABENBUILT_IN_TYPES_GENERIC.htm) named `DATA`. For objects (instances), a similar type named `OBJECT` exists. The generic type `ANY` will contain either one of these, but it's rather pointless to use it for both objects and values at the same time, because you'll end up handling data with references which can be really error prone (and is not something you should attempt to do if you don't know about generic types in the first place).